# Error in IPv6 increment script (bash) - can't find the mistake

Tags: bash, ipv6

per my last question, I managed to increment a given IPv6 Address by 1 to have the next possible address - hooray it works :)

But only until I hit the :ffff IP - the next would obviously be :1:0000 but my script is not "behaving" in a sane way - and I cannot figure out why :(

```
#!/bin/bash



initialipv6address="2001:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:ffff"
echo $initialipv6address


function ipv6_increment {
  IFS=':' read -r -a fields <<< "$initialipv6address"

  carry=1

  for ((i=${#fields[@]}-1; i>=0; i--)); do
    fields[$i]=$((16#${fields[i]}+carry))

    if [[ ${fields[$i]} -ge 65536 ]]; then
      carry=1
      fields[$i]=$((16#${fields[i]}-65536))
    else
      carry=0
    fi
  done

  printf "%04x:%04x:%04x:%04x:%04x:%04x:%04x:%04x\n" "${fields[@]}"
}



newipv6address=$(ipv6_increment "$initialipv6address")
echo "$newipv6address"
```

Output expected:

```
2001:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:ffff
2001:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001:0000
```

Output is in reality:

```
2001:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:ffff
2001:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0001:55536 <-- WTF?????
```

It seems like it correctly sets the value to 1 but I cannot figure out where the 55536 is coming from :(

Comment: You're getting confused between decimal and hexadecimal representations of the numbers. You read them in as hex, but every time you store them (after adding `carry` or subtracting 65536) they're stored as decimal. You get multiple hex -> decimal conversions on the same number, which makes a complete mess. My recommendation would be that after reading them in hex, you do a single conversion to decimal (storing the converted numbers in a different array), then do the math in decimal, and convert back to hex in the output.

Comment: `fields[$i]=$((16#${fields[i]}-65536))` => trying to process what is now a decimal value (`$fields[i]`) as a hex; remove the `16#`